# What do the +x next to my question in notifications mean?

Tags: support

First of all, I absolutely *l*o*v*e* that there is a meta SE. This is great.

Anyway, I asked a question, and I got two notifications after an  answer. One was just a green +10 next to my question, no info or other description in the notification, and the other was the same but +7. What did I get these points for? Are these reputation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the green +X icons are notifications of your reputation change. Take a look at **[What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)**. If you see a +7, it's likely that you accepted an answer and got an upvote on your question. For a +10, that would likely result from a pair of upvotes on a question or a single upvote on an answer.